# Confused about Full-Subtractor truth table

Tags: digital-logic

I'm a little confused about the 011 condition in the Full-Subtractor truth table.

[image]

I don't get how the output can be D = 0, B = 1.  Since D = A - B - C, that gives D = 0 - 1 - 1 = -2

How does a difference of 0, and borrow of 1 represent a -2?  Makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"How does a difference of 0, and borrow of 1 represent a -2? Makes no sense at all."

That makes perfect sense, because a borrow is in effect a -1 in the next column (to the left), which has a weight twice the weight of the column we are working on. Hence when a 1 in your column represent 1, borrowing (= subtracting) 1 from the next column (to the left) represents -2.

Answer (score 0):

Think about the *difference* and *borrow* in the reverse order. A borrow of 1 and a difference of 0 can be interpreted as a two-bit result of \$10_2\$. If your binary number system allows negative numbers then they are almost certainly two's-complement, and \$10_2\$ in two's-complement is indeed equivalent to \$-2_{10}\$.